# Work with a consequent mobile app

Tags: usability, mobile, enterprise

I'm a developer and I have to participate in the creation of screens/mockup for our new mobile app.
We have an ERP which manages a lot of activities of a company. For example: human resources, accounting, purchases and stocks of materials, order management with a supplier, etc. Our new mobile app will have to interface with this ERP.

There are two possibilities :

- 1 activity = 1 mobile app : an app for human resources, another for orders, ...
- A global app : easier for the user but we will have to manage many (many) screens and we don't know if it is user friendly

We would appreciate some help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a best practice for this. If you look at WeChat, or even your phone's browser: both support a large number of sub-applications (most of which aren't even related, unlike your use case).

Having multiple apps has the advantage of being more flexible (e.g. using different frameworks for a couple of them, update them independently, using less storage if you only need very specific apps), but it will be harder to enforce a certain common style among them. Anyway, different apps can communicate with each other, sharing data (even login credentials) and hotlink to each other. So from an end-user perspective, having multiple apps doesn't need to be a problem either.

Comment: Okay, so it depends on our need.
Do you think that an app have a "limit" in features number ?

Comment: My opinion doesn't matter; the opinion of your users does.

Comment: At one of the companies I used to work in, the situation was a bit extreme. We had about 6 mobile and web apps allowing us to do the same function, ie accessing customer information and it was confusing at times which platform we should use to do our work. I’d suggest to consider putting your ERP system onto one mobile app instead. You may like to verify my hypothesis with your colleagues.